# Distibuting objects into baskets

Tags: combinatorics

I will present how to solve such exercise

In how many ways can you place 67 non-distinguishable objects in 8 baskets ?

Comment: Must you have at least one object in each basket or not?  Are the baskets distinguishable?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you are adding numbers. So you got the equation 1+1+1+1...+1=67. Now you can place 7 markers. The question basically asks you, how many ways are there to place the markers. The only constraint is that you can not change the order of the markers, so for example marker 3 has to come after 1 and 2 but never before 4. Can you figure out the number of different ways?

Answer (score 0):

Using the following rule :

(m+k-1)! / m! x (k-1)! , we will get the right answer easily.

In this case it will be :  (67+7)!/(67! x 7!)

Comment: You are assuming that baskets may have no objects, but then it should be $(m-1)!k!$ in the denominator.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))  Also please use parentheses to show that the last term is in the denominator.  This format is not clear.